# powershell to extract values between two xml tags and save to a txt file

Tags: xml, powershell, scripting

In PowerShell I'm trying to retrieve all the values between 2 XML tags.

Example code shows:

```
<Report name="result_many fail" summary="20" yes=19 no="1" finished=20>
```

so my txt file should look like this:

name: result_many fail, summary 20, yes 19, no 1, finished 20

```
$text = Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.xml
$text | Select-Xml -XPath '//Report[@finished]
>result.txt
```

but this doesn't work

Could someone give me hint ?

Comment: The `Report` tag you showed has no `category` attribute, hence no matches for `[@category=...]`. Try `... |Select-Xml -XPath '//Report[@finished]'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks please check my edit , is this the right way to save the result in a txt file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attributes in the example need quotes and there is no end tag `</Report>`

Anyway, using `Select-Xml` to capture the text for that node and output it to textfile, you can do

```
('<Report name="result_many fail" summary="20" yes="19" no="1" finished="20">blablabla</Report>' | 
Select-Xml -XPath '//Report[@finished]').Node.InnerText |
Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\result.txt'
```

<sup>Instead of `.InnerText` you can also write `.'#text'`</sup>